# One json file is written and read by node.js and some other application problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js server (express.js) and I have a json file that I use to read and write data (simple api).
When the node.js server is stopped, that other application adds data to the json file without any problems.
When the node.js server is started that other application sees that json file as an empty file, probably
because the node.js server keeps it open.
In node.js I use `fs.readFile` and it closes the json file after reading, so I don't think that's the problem.
All this is happening on a local windows machine.
Has anyone had a similar problem sharing a single file with node.js and some other application?
If anyone had a direction to guide me, where to look for a solution.

Thank you for your time!

@jfriend00
As for that other application, it was written in clarion and I don't have access at the moment.
That application rarely writes data to that file.
Here's how I read and write the file:

```
function load(fileName, path, callback) {    
    let jsonPath = "";
    if(fileName == "companies") {
        jsonPath = __dirname + "\\..\\..\\";
    } else {
        jsonPath = path;
    }    
    fs.readFile(jsonPath + fileName.toUpperCase() + '.JSON', function (err, data) {    
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === "ENOENT") {                
                console.log("File '" + fileName.toUpperCase() + ".JSON' not found!");
                callback([]);
                return;
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
        callback(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
    });
} 


function save(fileName, path, array) {
    let jsonPath = "";
    if(fileName == "companies") {
        jsonPath = __dirname + "\\..\\..\\";
    } else {
        jsonPath = path;
    } 
    fs.writeFile(jsonPath + fileName.toUpperCase() + '.JSON', JSON.stringify(array), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Change the name of the file when you write to it, change it back when you are finished.,

Comment: I think you'd have to show us the reading/write code in both apps and how often they are called.  Only then could we evaluate what might be going on.  `fs.readFile()` all by itself only has the file open for a brief moment while it reads it and after that the file is again available for anyone else to read/write.  FYI, real-time sharing and modifying data between processes is a lot easier with a simple database that is built for this express purpose and implements the proper concurrency tools to protect the integrity of the data while being access by multiple processes.

Comment: @Grumpy I will give a suggestion to try that variant, since I do not work in that other application. I tried to edit the json file in an editor while node.js server is running and there are no problems. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Note that many editors explicitly allow the file to be edited while it's open in the editor (and they just update the editor with the latest data).  `fs.readFile()`,  while it is reading, would NOT want the data to be manipulated in the middle of read as you would potentially get corrupted or inconsistent data that was partially updated.

Comment: How often do you call `load()` or `save()`?  Also, not that your two `throw err` don't do anything useful.  They throw into an asynchronous callback which is not something you can catch or handle or log anywhere.   The first thing to do is to log those errors and then design a way to communicate them back to the caller via the callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you! I'll try to do that. By the way, I call load() and save() quite often.

Comment: Any possibility that your own calls to `load()` and `save()` are conflicting with each other (calling `load()` while `save()` is in progress), all within your own nodejs process?  Or maybe even calling `save()` while an existing `save()` is still in progress?  These are both asynchronous and you're calling them frequently so if you're not explicitly preventing them from one being called while the other is in progress, that's a possibility that you have your own local concurrency issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 They haven't conflict with each other. It works with Angular in front end pretty good. That third application (clarion app) instead of adding data, it deletes everything from the json file and writes at the beginning of the file new data. So, everything works properly until the third application intervenes. On the other hand, when the node.js server is stopped, that clarion app works properly. So, some text editor has no problem editing the json file and that clarion application has a problem. I apologize for these long comments.

Comment: So, it just sounds like your frequent reading/write to this file conflicts with the occasional writing of the file in Clarion.  You'll have to either implement some sort of file locking scheme and/or a retry scheme so whoever gets blocked by the other can just wait a bit and retry.  Or, put the data in a database and let the database manage concurrency for you.

Answer (score 0):

That software which I share json with, needs nice format, not an one line data.
So, I have to added two more parameters in `JSON.stringify(array, null, 2)` to format data nicely wen a calling `fs.writeFile` method.
I totally forgot this.
This was two days of agony.